# How to convert jquery to Angular in $(".video:last").after(data);

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

$(".video:last").after(data);

in **ng-repeat** Angular

```
  $http({
          method : "GET",
          url : base_url + 'video/get_video_list',
          params: {last_video_id : ID}
    }).success(function(data){

        $scope.videos = data;

    });//End http
```

Please Help Me T_T

Comment: Sorry, it's little bit unclear what and where to change jquery to angular...

Comment: Question is not clear, please add more details.

Comment: close votes for the question since you're not responding....

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you are finding the last DOM element with a class of 'videos', `$(".video:last")`, and then inserting the content from your data variable after that, `.after(data);` and also based on you bolding **ng-repeat** I'm assuming you are using an ng-repeat for $scope.videos in your partial.... you can access the last item in an ng-repeat via `$last`.

[Here is a list of other ng-repeat variables](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

if you set your data equal to a $scope value (i.e. `$scope.myData`) you can interpolate that into your last ng-repeat item. i.e:

```
<div ng-if="$last">{{myData}}</div>
```

But to be honest I'm not sure what you're asking...

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

i try to **Infinite Scrolling**
http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

i can not show data when scroll

every function loadMore() show in ng-repeat replace in old value  T_T

i hope use Angular for Good Filter Sort Data in Infinite-scroll

thank for Answer me..

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('app', ['infinite-scroll']);
 app.controller('DemoController', function($scope, $http) {
  

   var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
   $scope.loading = true;

    var ID = $(".video_box:last").attr("id");

    console.log('Value Id ///////////');
    console.log(ID);

    console.log('//////////////// load more ////////////');


   $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';  
  $http({
     method : "GET",
     url : base_url + 'video/get_video_list',
     params: {last_video_id : ID}
  }).success(function(data){

 

   $scope.videos = data;
  

   console.log('//////////////// success Data ////////////');
   $scope.loading = false; 
          
  });//End http 

  };//End loadMore



});//End Controller

// we create a simple directive to modify behavior of <ul>
app.directive("whenScrolled", function(){
  console.log('whenscroll--------------');
  return{
    
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    
      // we get a list of elements of size 1 and need the first element
      raw = elem[0];
    
      // we load more elements when scrolled past a limit
      elem.bind("scroll", function(){
        if(raw.scrollTop+raw.offsetHeight+5 >= raw.scrollHeight){
          scope.loading = true;
          console.log('whenscroll--------------');
        // we can give any function which loads more elements into the list
          scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrolled);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

```html
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='DemoController'>


  <div  infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2' >
 
    <div ng-repeat="video in videos" >
 
  <div id='{{video.id}}' class='video_box'>
      <li class='block'>
      <a href='<? echo base_url();?>video/view/{{video.id}}' class='video-thumbnail' >
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{video.url}}/1.jpg" alt='{{video.title}}'/>
    <div ng-if="$last" ><h2>{{video.title}}</h2></div>
   </a>
   </li>
  </div>
 
 </div><!-- End video in videos -->
 <div data-ng-show='loading'>Loading</div>
  </div><!--End infinite-scroll-->
</div><!--End App -->
```